# pushing migration from laravel to vercel Pgsql

Tags: laravel, migration, vercel

I'm trying to migrate my migrations from `laravel` to a `vercel postGresql` database.

However, I'm getting an error regarding.

```
PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSLMODE => PDO::SSLMODE_REQUIRE,
```

These guys not existing or undefined.

I got this code from copilot and I'm stuck trying to use this code and migrate the migrations from `laravel`.

```
    'pgsql' => [
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => 'ep-cool-unit-80954760.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com',
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => 'hcvercel',
        'username' => 'default',
        'password' => 'ZmJ0P2AVSdoF',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'search_path' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => env('PGSQL_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
        'options' => [
            PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSLMODE => PDO::SSLMODE_REQUIRE,
            'endpoint' => 'ep-cool-unit-80954760-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com',
        ],
    ],
```

any other workaround for this?

Comment: Try setting sslmode to 'require'.